# Count number of pedestrians on an arbitrary street

Tags: geospatial, city, demographics

I'm looking for data that allow me to estimate the number of pedestrians and/or cars passing by on a certain part of a certain street at a certain time. Any ideas on where and/or how I can get this data?

I'm also interested in demographics of such a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any such dataset.

However, there are many open webcams for streets around the world.
Feeding the stream of such a webcam into a people counting system such as https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/ could give you some data.

Unfortunately the license of such webcams is most often unclear, and thus can not be considered open data.